# launching parallel bsub job in clearcase environment

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, clearcase, lsf

ClearCase does not work in conjunction with LSF distributed multi-host parallel job if more than 1 hosts are specified.

Reason: ClearCase does not mount the file system on all hosts when dispatching multi-host simulations to the LSF system

the job is terminated because included files are not found or cannot be output because the file system does not exist on all hosts.

The ClearCase + LSF implementation has to guarantee by construction that the job is dispatched correctly in 100% of all cases, which is currently not the case.

please help me on this issue.

Comment: Are you talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF?

Comment: yes I am talking about load sharing facility

Comment: What kind of views (snapshot? dynamic?) would you like to mount on those hosts?

Comment: I am using dynamic view and mounting the vob on executed host

Comment: Is the view storage path of that dynamic view accessible from all the hosts involved

Comment: view storage path is accessible on all hosts

Comment: Is there any way to issue a command `cleartool mount \yourVob` in order to lake sure the filesystem is there on each lfs host?

Comment: in first, I am able to mount the VOB but it is not happening in the second host `bsub -q batch -n 2 -R 'type==X64LIN && osrel==50' -R 'span[ptile=1]' " job_cmd` this is the command i am executing

Comment: is there any way to distribute the multiple job commands to the host's EXAMPLE: in the first host, set the ClearCase environment and execute  `ls and pwd` in the second host  set the ClearCase environment and execute `echo "MESSAGE", pwd`

Comment: 3 questions: 1) Are these "private" VOBs? 2) Is the job explicitly mounting those VOBs and failing? 3) What user do the jobs run as? If the VOB's are private, and the job is running as a user other than the VOB owner, the mount will fail. The LSF-heavy customers also have literally hundreds of "public" VOBs, and I don't think that's coincidence.

Comment: 1) Ans: yes. there are private vobs

Comment: 1) Ans: yes. there are privateVOBS(project groups will access theseVOBS) 2) Ans: I am unable to execute the mount_vob command on the second host 3)Ans: the user is trying to launch parallel jobs on multiple hosts `bsub -E 'test_cmd' -q batch -n 2 -R 'type==X64LIN && osrel==50' -R 'span[ptile=1]' "pwd"` is there any way to execute pre-execution script on multiple hosts ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LSF/Clearcase integration uses the daemon.wrap program to set the view on the execution host and then launch the job inside the view.  That wrapper doesn't support cross-host parallel jobs.

You'll have to try to work around the limitation in your job script.  You can disable the daemon wrapper by making sure the $CLEARCASE_ROOT is not set in your job submission environment.  Then in the job script, in the execution environment, and in each process that is participating in the parallel job the job script can call `cleartool setview <options> <real job command>`.

If you launch your job with blaunch then it might make things easier.  Without blaunch, LSF will start a single process on the first execution host.  With blaunch, LSF will launch one process per slot, and launch it on all of the allocated execution hosts.  With blaunch, each process can then set the view and start the real job.

Good luck!

Comment: It may be a good idea to ensure that the "real job command" verifies that any VOBs it depends on are mounted as well. Some folks use private VOBs to limit the number of automouting VOBs on Unix, and in that case it's better to avoid making assumptions abut what is mounted. (You could use a separate job to make sure the VOBs are mounted before starting the "real" job.